# Retorno de conteúdo para a aplicação cliente com header definido

Tags: php, html, json, xml

Tenho uma aplicação que retorna conteúdo JSON do PHP para uma página HTML, porém faço isso sem definir o `header`, como, por exemplo : `header('Content-Type: application/json');`, ou seja, na aplicação não tem essa declaração.

Funciona normalmente, o browser consegue manipular normalmente o JSON com JavaScript.

Porém um dia resolvi definir o `header` e ao chamar o conteúdo diretamente pela URL percebi que o conteúdo na página, a fonte do texto, fica menor ao definir o `header` passando no `Content-Type` o valor `application/json` comparando se não tivesse definido o mesmo ou com o `Content-Type` apresentando um valor diferente, como se fosse retornar um HTML por exemplo `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`.

A partir disso gostaria de saber. Qual a diferença em definir o `header` ou não em uma aplicação PHP? Existe algum aumento de performance definindo o `header` já que o texto mudou para uma fonte e um estilo diferente quando o conteúdo era JSON? Por que essa diferença com a forma como o conteúdo é exibido na tela?

Comment: Como foi feita a requisição?

Comment: Com GET e passando um pequeno valor no parâmetro para identificação do método a ser chamado. Mas queria saber sobre essa diferença.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Comment: Ainda não foi resolvida, vc também tem curiosidade em saber?